# PHP SQL Combine Records Within Foreach()

Tags: php, sql

I'm revisiting this as I'm working on another page that I want to use the same concept.
[This page](http://www.flcbranson.org/estherssistershusband.php) shows the output that I'm currently getting from my MSSQL server.

I have a table of venue information (name, address, etc...) that our events happen on.  Separately, I have a table of the actual events that are scheduled (an event may happen multiple times in one day and/or over multiple days).  I join those tables with a query (as seen below).

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=Sermons", "", "");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.TblSermon.Day, dbo.TblSermon.Date, dbo.TblSermon.Time, dbo.TblSermon.Speaker, dbo.TblSermon.Series, dbo.TblSermon.Sarasota, dbo.TblSermon.NonFlc, dbo.TblJoinSermonLocation.MeetingName, dbo.TblLocation.Location, dbo.TblLocation.Pastors, dbo.TblLocation.Address, dbo.TblLocation.City, dbo.TblLocation.State, dbo.TblLocation.Zip, dbo.TblLocation.Country, dbo.TblLocation.Phone, dbo.TblLocation.Email, dbo.TblLocation.WebAddress
        FROM dbo.TblLocation RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.TblJoinSermonLocation ON dbo.TblLocation.ID = dbo.TblJoinSermonLocation.Location RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.TblSermon ON dbo.TblJoinSermonLocation.Sermon = dbo.TblSermon.ID
        WHERE (dbo.TblSermon.Date >= { fn NOW() })
        ORDER BY dbo.TblSermon.Date, dbo.TblSermon.Time";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($row);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
    unset($row);
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

So, as it loops through the query results, it creates an array for each record.

```
Array
(
    [Day] => Tuesday
    [Date] => 2012-10-30 00:00:00.000
    [Time] => 07:00 PM
    [Speaker] => Keith Moore
    [Location] => The Ark Church
    [Pastors] => Alan & Joy Clayton
    [Address] => 450 Humble Tank Rd.
    [City] => Conroe
    [State] => TX
    [Zip] => 77305.0
    [Phone] => (936) 756-1988
    [Email] => info@thearkchurch.com
    [WebAddress] => http://www.thearkchurch.org
)
Array
(
    [Day] => Wednesday
    [Date] => 2012-10-31 00:00:00.000
    [Time] => 07:00 PM
    [Speaker] => Keith Moore
    [Location] => The Ark Church
    [Pastors] => Alan & Joy Clayton
    [Address] => 450 Humble Tank Rd.
    [City] => Conroe
    [State] => TX
    [Zip] => 77305.0
    [Phone] => (936) 756-1988
    [Email] => info@thearkchurch.com
    [WebAddress] => http://www.thearkchurch.org
)
Array
(
    [Day] => Tuesday
    [Date] => 2012-11-06 00:00:00.000
    [Time] => 07:00 PM
    [Speaker] => Keith Moore
    [Location] => Fellowship Of Faith Christian Center
    [Pastors] => Michael & Joan Kalstrup
    [Address] => 18999 Hwy. 59
    [City] => Oakland
    [State] => IA
    [Zip] => 51560.0
    [Phone] => (712) 482-3455
    [Email] => ffcc@frontiernet.net
    [WebAddress] => http://www.fellowshipoffaith.cc
)
Array
(
    [Day] => Wednesday
    [Date] => 2012-11-14 00:00:00.000
    [Time] => 07:00 PM
    [Speaker] => Keith Moore
    [Location] => Faith Family Church
    [Pastors] => Michael & Barbara Cameneti
    [Address] => 8200 Freedom Ave NW
    [City] => Canton
    [State] => OH
    [Zip] => 44720.0
    [Phone] => (330) 492-0925
    [Email] => 
    [WebAddress] => http://www.myfaithfamily.com
)
```

What I'm wanting to do is combine those arrays, in some fashion, so that the venue information isn't repeated every time, but each date/time is show.

I tried typing it out in array style, but couldn't figure out the appropriate multi-dimensionality for it.  I'm just pasting how I would like it to display, since that is how it will end up.

```
The Ark Church
    Contact:
        Alan & Joy Clayton
        450 Humble Tank Rd.
        Conroe, TX  77305
        (936) 756-1988
        info@thearkchurch.com
        http://www.thearkchurch.org
    Meetings:
        Tuesday, 2012-10-30 07:00 PM
        Wednesday, 2012-10-31 07:00 PM

Fellowship Of Faith Christian Center
    Contact:
        Michael & Joan Kalstrup
        18999 Hwy. 59
        Oakland, IA  51560
        (712) 482-3455
        ffcc@frontiernet.net
        http://www.fellowshipoffaith.cc
    Meetings:
        Tuesday, 2012-11-06 07:00 PM

Faith Family Church
    Contact:
        Michael & Barbara Cameneti
        8200 Freedom Ave NW
        Canton, OH  44720
        (330) 492-0925
        http://www.myfaithfamily.com
    Meetings:
        Wednesday, 2012-11-14 07:00 PM
```

It doesn't necessarily have to end up like that, but it should give a good idea of what I'm looking for.

I don't necessarily *have* to create a new array.  I just want to **not** show the same information over and over and over.

I was thinking that I could just do some form of compare, in `foreach()` that says something along the lines of "if Location is the same as previous Location", but I haven't figured out how to do it (is there a way to cache a previous variable with doing `$location1 = [Location]`, `$location2 = [Location]`, etc...?

One thing to note...

These examples don't have different speakers, but sometimes there are.  I would like to be able to access the speaker, somehow.  I assume that I would want it bound to the actual event.

JJ

Comment: Without code and maybe a database schema everyone is just guessing

Comment: I updated this question and didn't know if it would stay buried or if the edit would automatically bump it.

Answer (score 0):

One technique: if you have a loop like this:

```
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) ) {
    list($time,$place,$etc) = $row;
    // display formatted data
}
```

try this instead:

```
$row = $query->fetch();
do {
    list($time,$place,$etc) = $row;
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    if ($time != $row[0] && $place != $row[1] && $etc != $row[2]) {
        // display formatted data
    }
} while ($row);
```

Comment: I've been trying to hack around with this and I'm either lost or we're not on the same page.  I'm getting it to where it will only show 1 record for each event (`if ($meeting != $row[7])`).  What I'm wanting is to show the event information once but all the dates associated with that event (as in the "I just want..." portion of my original post).  Are the results that I'm getting what you thought would happen or am I doing something incorrectly?  I don't want to past my full code in this little comment.

Answer (score 0):

I usually would approach a problem like this by creating a two-dimensinoal array, indexed by date then ID or in your case by ID then date.

Loop through events (the first dimension) and print out the contents of that event - while in there loop through the dates on that event and print those out as a list as in your example.

Comment: So, in this case, the first dimension would be the venue and the second dimension would be the dates?  That's an interesting thought.