# Removing Duplicate Data From SQL Query Output For Display On A Web Page

Tags: php, database, sql

I had asked [a similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086726/php-sql-combine-records-within-foreach) but didn't really get anywhere.

[This page](http://www.flcbranson.org/events-array.php) shows the output that I'm currently getting from my MSSQL server.

I have a table of venue information (name, address, etc...) that our events happen on.  Separately, I have a table of the actual events that are scheduled (an event may happen multiple times in one day and/or over multiple days).  I join those tables with this query:

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=Sermons", "", "");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.TblSermon.Day, dbo.TblSermon.Date, dbo.TblSermon.Time, dbo.TblSermon.Speaker, dbo.TblSermon.Series, dbo.TblSermon.Sarasota, dbo.TblSermon.NonFlc, dbo.TblJoinSermonLocation.MeetingName, dbo.TblLocation.Location, dbo.TblLocation.Pastors, dbo.TblLocation.Address, dbo.TblLocation.City, dbo.TblLocation.State, dbo.TblLocation.Zip, dbo.TblLocation.Country, dbo.TblLocation.Phone, dbo.TblLocation.Email, dbo.TblLocation.WebAddress
        FROM dbo.TblLocation RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.TblJoinSermonLocation ON dbo.TblLocation.ID = dbo.TblJoinSermonLocation.Location RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.TblSermon ON dbo.TblJoinSermonLocation.Sermon = dbo.TblSermon.ID
        WHERE (dbo.TblSermon.Date >= { fn NOW() })
        ORDER BY dbo.TblSermon.Date, dbo.TblSermon.Time";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($row);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
    unset($row);
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

So, as it loops through the query results, it creates an array for each record and ends up like this:

```
Array
(
    [Day] => Tuesday
    [Date] => 2012-10-30 00:00:00.000
    [Time] => 07:00 PM
    [Speaker] => Keith Moore
    [Location] => The Ark Church
    [Pastors] => Alan & Joy Clayton
    [Address] => 450 Humble Tank Rd.
    [City] => Conroe
    [State] => TX
    [Zip] => 77305.0
    [Phone] => (936) 756-1988
    [Email] => info@thearkchurch.com
    [WebAddress] => http://www.thearkchurch.org
)
Array
(
    [Day] => Wednesday
    [Date] => 2012-10-31 00:00:00.000
    [Time] => 07:00 PM
    [Speaker] => Keith Moore
    [Location] => The Ark Church
    [Pastors] => Alan & Joy Clayton
    [Address] => 450 Humble Tank Rd.
    [City] => Conroe
    [State] => TX
    [Zip] => 77305.0
    [Phone] => (936) 756-1988
    [Email] => info@thearkchurch.com
    [WebAddress] => http://www.thearkchurch.org
)
Array
(
    [Day] => Tuesday
    [Date] => 2012-11-06 00:00:00.000
    [Time] => 07:00 PM
    [Speaker] => Keith Moore
    [Location] => Fellowship Of Faith Christian Center
    [Pastors] => Michael & Joan Kalstrup
    [Address] => 18999 Hwy. 59
    [City] => Oakland
    [State] => IA
    [Zip] => 51560.0
    [Phone] => (712) 482-3455
    [Email] => ffcc@frontiernet.net
    [WebAddress] => http://www.fellowshipoffaith.cc
)
Array
(
    [Day] => Wednesday
    [Date] => 2012-11-14 00:00:00.000
    [Time] => 07:00 PM
    [Speaker] => Keith Moore
    [Location] => Faith Family Church
    [Pastors] => Michael & Barbara Cameneti
    [Address] => 8200 Freedom Ave NW
    [City] => Canton
    [State] => OH
    [Zip] => 44720.0
    [Phone] => (330) 492-0925
    [Email] => 
    [WebAddress] => http://www.myfaithfamily.com
)
```

As you can see, The Ark Church and its associated contact information is duplicated, so when I work with those arrays and output them to the page, I see a bunch of duplicate content.

I'd like to remove the duplicate information so that I get results similar to this:

```
The Ark Church
Alan & Joy Clayton
450 Humble Tank Rd.
Conroe, TX  77305
(936) 756-1988
info@thearkchurch.com
http://www.thearkchurch.org
Meetings:
Tuesday, 2012-10-30 07:00 PM
Wednesday, 2012-10-31 07:00 PM

Fellowship Of Faith Christian Center
Michael & Joan Kalstrup
18999 Hwy. 59
Oakland, IA  51560
(712) 482-3455
ffcc@frontiernet.net
http://www.fellowshipoffaith.cc
Meetings:
Tuesday, 2012-11-06 07:00 PM

Faith Family Church
Michael & Barbara Cameneti
8200 Freedom Ave NW
Canton, OH  44720
(330) 492-0925
http://www.myfaithfamily.com
Meetings:
Wednesday, 2012-11-14 07:00 PM
```

It doesn't necessarily have to end up like that (I'm not looking for code specific for these results, but a concept of how to not show the duplicated information).  I'm assuming that an additional `foreach` or `while` will do it, but I haven't figured out any logic that says `<?php if ($location == $previouslocation) echo ""; ?>`.

Comment: I am  not sure this is relevant to your problem.. but did you try SELECT DISTINCT...

Comment: I hadn't but wouldn't that require using only one `select something`?

Comment: I think you can .. SELECT DISTINCT TOP .. should work..

Comment: @Dinesh I'll have to play with this, next week.  I'm out of the office for the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to want to use a GROUP BY ... HAVING statement.

Try adding something like

```
GROUP BY dbo.TblSermon.Date HAVING MIN(dbo.TblSermon.Date)
```

Comment: It looks like I'll have to change my query around to work with `GROUP BY`.  The things that I've tested, thus-far, have only resulted in errors.  It looks like I will need to create an aggregate function in order to work.  I'll continue on.

Answer (score 0):

Wow...

I finally accomplished what I wanted (and it was a pain in the butt).  I'm sure there are other ways (and probably better ways) of doing it.  This actually gives me the results in a fashion that I want, though.

PHP code...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Events | Faith Life Church - Branson, MO</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Events <abbr title="And">&amp;</abbr> Meetings</h1>
<?php
// get events from a database
try {
    // MSSQL has the ability to use Windows Authentication by not passing a username or password
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=Sermons", "", "");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // get events from the main database
    $getoriginalevents = "SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.TblSermon.Day, dbo.TblSermon.Date, dbo.TblSermon.Time, dbo.TblSermon.Speaker, dbo.TblSermon.Series, dbo.TblSermon.Sermon, dbo.TblSermon.Sarasota, dbo.TblSermon.NonFlc, dbo.TblJoinSermonLocation.MeetingName, dbo.TblLocation.Location, dbo.TblLocation.Pastors, dbo.TblLocation.Address, dbo.TblLocation.City, dbo.TblLocation.State, dbo.TblLocation.Zip, dbo.TblLocation.Country, dbo.TblLocation.Phone, dbo.TblLocation.Email, dbo.TblLocation.WebAddress
        FROM dbo.TblLocation RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.TblJoinSermonLocation ON dbo.TblLocation.ID = dbo.TblJoinSermonLocation.Location RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.TblSermon ON dbo.TblJoinSermonLocation.Sermon = dbo.TblSermon.ID
        WHERE (dbo.TblSermon.Date >= { fn NOW() }) AND (dbo.TblSermon.Notes NOT LIKE '%Not to be put on our Website%' OR dbo.TblSermon.Notes IS NULL)
        ORDER BY dbo.TblSermon.Date, dbo.TblSermon.Time";
    // prepared statements are good for security and speed
    $originalevents = $dbh->prepare($getoriginalevents);
    $originalevents->execute();
    // create an array using names instead of keys ($originalevent["Location"] instead of $originalevent[1])
    $originalevents->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // delete the data from the temporary events table (we don't want duplicate events)
    $dbh->query("DELETE FROM dbo.Events");

    // insert events into a temporary events table (the original database doesn't contain all the information so PHP creates some)
    // this will be executed within foreach ()
    $putprocessedevent = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO dbo.Events (Title, Speaker, Venue, Pastors, Street, City, State, Zip, Map, Phone, Email, Website, Date) VALUES (:title, :speaker, :venue, :pastors, :street, :city, :state, :zip, :map, :phone, :email, :website, :date)");

    // for every record that the initial query produces...
    foreach ($originalevents as $originalevent) {
        // redefine the variables
        $title = $originalevent["Location"];
        if ($originalevent["MeetingName"]) $title = $originalevent["MeetingName"];
        if ($originalevent["Sermon"]) $title = $originalevent["Sermon"];
        if ($originalevent["Series"]) $title = $originalevent["Series"];
        $speaker = $originalevent["Speaker"];
        // if the record ISN'T from Sarasota or the road...
        if ($originalevent["Sarasota"] == 0 && $originalevent["NonFlc"] == 0) {
            $venue = "Faith Life Church";
            $pastors = "Keith & Phyllis Moore";
            $street = "3701 State Highway 76";
            $city = "Branson";
            $state = "MO";
            $zip = "65616";
            $map = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Faith+Life+Church+Branson+MO+65616";
            $phone = "+1-417-334-9233";
            $email = "general@moorelife.org";
            $website = "http://www.flcbranson.org";
        }
        // if the record IS from Sarasota...
        if ($originalevent["Sarasota"] == 1) {
            $venue = "Faith Life Church";
            $pastors = "Keith & Phyllis Moore";
            $street = "6980 Professional Parkway East";
            $city = "Sarasota";
            $state = "FL";
            $zip = "34240";
            $map = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Faith+Life+Church+Sarasota+FL+34240";
            $phone = "+1-941-388-6961";
            $email = "general@moorelife.org";
            $website = "http://www.flcsarasota.org";
        }
        // if the record IS from the road...
        if ($originalevent["NonFlc"] == 1) {
            $venue = $originalevent["Location"];
            if ($originalevent["Pastors"]) $pastors = $originalevent["Pastors"];
            $street = $originalevent["Address"];
            $city = $originalevent["City"];
            $state = $originalevent["State"];
            $zip = substr($originalevent["Zip"], 0, -2);
            $map = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" . str_replace(" ", "+", $originalevent["Location"]) . "+" . str_replace(" ", "+", $originalevent["City"]) . "+" . $originalevent["State"] . "+" . substr($originalevent["Zip"], 0 ,-2);
            if ($originalevent["Phone"]) $phone = "+1-" . substr($originalevent["Phone"], 1, 3) . "-" . substr($originalevent["Phone"], -8);
            if ($originalevent["Email"]) $email = $originalevent["Email"];
            if ($originalevent["WebAddress"]) $website = $originalevent["WebAddress"];
        }

        $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($originalevent["Date"]));
        if ($originalevent["Time"]) $date = date("c", strtotime(substr($originalevent["Date"], 0, -13) . $originalevent["Time"]));

        // execute the actual insertion of new events
        $putprocessedevent->execute(array(":title" => $title, ":speaker" => $speaker, ":venue" => $venue, ":pastors" => $pastors, ":street" => $street, ":city" => $city, ":state" => $state, ":zip" => $zip, ":map" => $map, ":phone" => $phone, ":email" => $email, ":website" => $website, ":date" => $date));
    }
    // kill the last record of the array
    unset($originalevent);

    // get events from the temporary events database
    $getprocessedtitles = "SELECT DISTINCT Title, MIN(EventsID) FROM dbo.Events GROUP BY Title ORDER BY MIN(EventsID)";
    $processedtitles = $dbh->prepare($getprocessedtitles);
    $processedtitles->execute();
    // create an array using names instead of keys ($originalevent["Location"] instead of $originalevent[1])
    $processedtitles->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // for every record that the new query produces...
    foreach ($processedtitles as $processedtitle) {
        $eventtitle = $processedtitle["Title"];
?>
<h2><?php echo $eventtitle; ?></h2>
<dl>
    <dt>Speakers</dt>
<?php
        // get dates from the temporary events database
        $getprocessedspeakers = "SELECT DISTINCT Speaker, MIN(EventsID) FROM dbo.Events WHERE Title LIKE '%" . $eventtitle . "%'GROUP BY Speaker ORDER BY MIN(EventsID)";
        $processedspeakers = $dbh->prepare($getprocessedspeakers);
        $processedspeakers->execute();
        // create an array using names instead of keys ($originalevent["Location"] instead of $originalevent[1])
        $processedspeakers->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($processedspeakers as $processedspeaker) {
            $eventspeaker = $processedspeaker["Speaker"];
?>
    <dd><?php echo $eventspeaker; ?></dd>
<?php
        }
?>
</dl>
<h3>Venue Information</h3>
<dl>
<?php
        // get dates from the temporary events database
        $getprocessedinfo = "SELECT Venue, Pastors, Street, City, State, Zip, Map, Phone, Email, Website FROM dbo.Events WHERE Title LIKE '%" . $eventtitle . "%'";
        $processedinfo = $dbh->prepare($getprocessedinfo);
        $processedinfo->execute();
        // create an array using names instead of keys ($originalevent["Location"] instead of $originalevent[1])
        // I used $processedinfo = $processedinfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); instead of $processedtitles->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); so that I wouldn't have to do a separate array (print_r($processedtitles); shows the actual query and not the results of the query)
        $processedinfo = $processedinfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $eventvenue = $processedinfo["Venue"];
        $eventpastors = $processedinfo["Pastors"];
        $eventstreet = $processedinfo["Street"];
        $eventcity = $processedinfo["City"];
        $eventstate = $processedinfo["State"];
        $eventzip = $processedinfo["Zip"];
        $eventmap = $processedinfo["Map"];
        $eventphone = $processedinfo["Phone"];
        $eventemail = $processedinfo["Email"];
        $eventwebsite = $processedinfo["Website"];
?>
    <dt>Venue</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $eventvenue; ?></dd>
    <dt>Pastors</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $eventpastors; ?></dd>
    <dt>Street</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $eventstreet; ?></dd>
    <dt>City</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $eventcity; ?></dd>
    <dt>State</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $eventstate; ?></dd>
    <dt>Zip</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $eventzip; ?></dd>
    <dt>Map</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $eventmap; ?></dd>
    <dt>Phone</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $eventphone; ?></dd>
    <dt>Email</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $eventemail; ?></dd>
    <dt>Website</dt>
    <dd><?php echo $eventwebsite; ?></dd>
</dl>
<h3>Event Dates</h3>
<ol>
<?php
        // get dates from the temporary events database
        $getprocesseddates = "SELECT Date FROM dbo.Events WHERE Title LIKE '%" . $eventtitle . "%'";
        $processeddates = $dbh->prepare($getprocesseddates);
        $processeddates->execute();
        // create an array using names instead of keys ($originalevent["Location"] instead of $originalevent[1])
        $processeddates->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // for every record that the new query produces...
        foreach ($processeddates as $processeddate) {
            $eventdate = $processeddate["Date"];
?>
    <li><?php echo $eventdate; ?></li>
<?php
        }
        // kill the last record of the array
        unset($processeddate);
?>
</ol>
<?php
    }
    // kill the last record of the array
    unset($processedtitle);

    // kill the database connection
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Resultant rendered HTML...

```
Events & Meetings

KCM Branson Victory Campaign 2013
Speakers
    Kenneth Copeland
    Gloria Copeland
Venue Information
Venue
    Faith Life Church
Pastors
    Keith & Phyllis Moore
Street
    3701 State Highway 76
City
    Branson
State
    MO
Zip
    65616
Map
    http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Faith+Life+Church+Branson+MO+65616
Phone
    +1-417-334-9233
Email
    general@moorelife.org
Website
    http://www.flcbranson.org
Event Dates
    1. 2013-03-07T19:00:00-06:00
    2. 2013-03-08T14:00:00-06:00
    3. 2013-03-08T19:00:00-06:00
    4. 2013-03-08T09:00:00-06:00
    5. 2013-03-09T09:30:00-06:00

Victory Family Church
Speakers
    Keith Moore 

Venue Information
Venue
    Victory Family Church
Pastors
    John & Michelle Nuzzo
Street
    21150 Route 19
City
    Cranberry Township
State
    PA
Zip
    16066
Map
    http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Victory+Family+Church+Cranberry+Township+PA+16066
Phone
    +1-724-453-6200
Email
    general@moorelife.org
Website
    http://www.lifeatvictory.com

Event Dates
    1. 2013-08-19T19:00:00-05:00
    2. 2013-08-20T19:00:00-05:00
    3. 2013-08-21T19:00:00-05:00
```

Maybe this experience will help someone else.  It has taken me nearly a year (off-and-on) to get this to work.  Feel free to post things that would make this cleaner or easier.